# Swing e-mail client throws javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException

Tags: java, swing, email, netbeans-7

I am trying to make an email client in NetBeans to send emails, but I am getting an `AuthenticationFailedException` in my code. This is my code (there are three classes):

**EmailClient.java**

```
package sendemail;

    public class EmailClient extends javax.swing.JFrame {

        SendMail sm=new SendMail();
        Settings set=new Settings();
        public EmailClient() {
            initComponents();
        }


        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        +Generated code                     

        private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
           // TODO add your handling code here:
            sm.setVisible(true);
        }                                        

        private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
            // TODO add your handling code here:
        }                                        

        private void jButton3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
            // TODO add your handling code here:
        }                                        

        private void jMenuItem2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
            // TODO add your handling code here:
            set.setVisible(true);
        }                                          

        public static void main(String args[]) {
            /* Create and display the form */
            java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    new EmailClient().setVisible(true);
                }
            });
        }

        // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
        private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
        private javax.swing.JButton jButton2;
        private javax.swing.JButton jButton3;
        private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
        private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
        private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
        private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel4;
        private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel5;
        private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel6;
        private javax.swing.JMenu jMenu4;
        private javax.swing.JMenu jMenu5;
        private javax.swing.JMenuBar jMenuBar2;
        private javax.swing.JMenuItem jMenuItem2;
        private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
        private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel3;
        private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel4;
        private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
        private javax.swing.JTextArea jTextArea1;
        // End of variables declaration                   
    }
```

**Settings.java**

```
package sendemail;
    import javax.swing.*;
    import java.awt.*;

    public class Settings extends javax.swing.JFrame {

        public String uname;
        public String pass;
        public String smtpserver;
        public String  port;
        /**
         * Creates new form Settings
         */
        public Settings() {
            initComponents();
        }

        public String getUname() {
            return uname;
        }

        public String getPass() {
            return pass;
        }

        public String getSmtpserver() {
            return smtpserver;
        }

        public String getPort() {
            return port;
        }



        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        +Generated Code                   

        private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
            // TODO add your handling code here:
           uname=jTextField1.getText().toString();
            pass=jPasswordField1.getPassword().toString();

            smtpserver=jComboBox1.getSelectedItem().toString();
            port=jComboBox2.getSelectedItem().toString();

            if(uname.equals("") || pass.equals("") || smtpserver.equals("") || port.equals("") )
        {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"All Fields are mandatory");
        }                                        
        else
            {
                setVisible(false);
            }

        }                                        

        private void jComboBox1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
            // TODO add your handling code here:
        }                                          

        public static void main(String args[]) {
            /* Create and display the form */
            java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    new Settings().setVisible(false);
                }
            });
        }

        // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
        private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
        private javax.swing.JComboBox jComboBox1;
        private javax.swing.JComboBox jComboBox2;
        private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
        private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
        private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
        private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel4;
        private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
        private javax.swing.JPasswordField jPasswordField1;
        private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField1;
        // End of variables declaration                   

    }
```

**SendMail.Java**

```
package sendemail;

    import java.util.Properties;
    import javax.mail.Message;
    import javax.mail.Session;
    import javax.mail.Transport;
    import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
    import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
    import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
    import java.awt.*;
    import javax.mail.*;
    import javax.mail.MessagingException;


    public class SendMail extends javax.swing.JFrame {

        Settings setfrm=new Settings();
        String subject;
        String from;

        public SendMail() {
            initComponents();
        }


        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        +Generated Code                    

        private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
            // TODO add your handling code here:
            try
            {
            final String user=setfrm.getUname();
            final String password=setfrm.getPass();
            String portnum=setfrm.getPort();
            String smtpname=setfrm.getSmtpserver();
            String to=jTextField1.getText();
            subject=jTextField2.getText();
            Properties properties=new Properties();
            properties.put("mail.smtp.host",smtpname.toString());
            properties.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port",portnum.toString());
            properties.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class","javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
            properties.put("mail.smtp.port",portnum.toString());
            properties.put("mail.smtp.auth","true");
            Session session=Session.getDefaultInstance(properties,
               new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                   protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication(){
                    return new PasswordAuthentication(user,password);

               }

               }

               );
            MimeMessage message=new MimeMessage(session);
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(user));
            message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(jTextField1.getText().toString()));
            message.setSubject(subject);
            message.setText(jTextArea1.getText());
            Transport.send(message);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"message sent");
            }
            catch(MessagingException mex)
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,mex);
            }
        }                                        

        private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
            // TODO add your handling code here:
        }                                        

        private void jTextField1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
            // TODO add your handling code here:
        }                                           

        public static void main(String args[]) {
            /* Create and display the form */
            java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    new SendMail().setVisible(true);
                }
            });
        }

        // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
        private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
        private javax.swing.JButton jButton2;
        private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
        private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
        private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
        private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
        private javax.swing.JTextArea jTextArea1;
        private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField1;
        private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField2;
        // End of variables declaration                   

    }
```

**Exception stack trace**

```
javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:306)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:156)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:105)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.connect(SMTPTransport.java:93)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:168)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:98)
    at sendemail.SendMail.jButton1ActionPerformed(SendMail.java:189)
    at sendemail.SendMail.access$100(SendMail.java:25)
    at sendemail.SendMail$2.actionPerformed(SendMail.java:77)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6505)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3311)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6270)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:735)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:708)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:706)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:705)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 2 minutes 46 seconds)
```

I am trying to send e-mail with `SendMail` class while the sender's email and password is entered from `Settings` and the `EmailClient` is just for setting `JFrames` visibility to `true` or `false` on buttons click.

```
SMTP server:smtp.gmail.com
port:465
```

I think the problem lies in the variables of `Authenticator` in `SendMail` class, but I am not sure what the problem actually is.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Try checking I believe the credentials are not correct, as smtp response also suggests. Codewise smtp code looks fine.

Answer (score 1):

> I think the problem lies in the variables of Authenticator in
>   SendMail.java....bu i don't know what the problem actually is......

Your problem is here:

```
pass = jPasswordField1.getPassword().toString();
```

This won't convert the char array retrieved by [getPassword()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JPasswordField.html#getPassword%28%29) method in the way you want to because it's calling `toString()` method on an array. You should replace that line by this one:

```
pass = String.valueOf(jPasswordField1.getPassword());
```

Also be aware that using `Session.getDefaultInstance()` method is discouraged. It's highly recommended use `Session.getInstance()` method instead because of this:

> The `Session.getDefaultInstance` method creates a new `Session` the first
>   time it's called, using the `Properties` that are passed. **Subsequent
>   calls will return that original `Session` and ignore any `Properties` you
>   pass in.** If you want to create different Sessions with different
>   properties, `Session.getDefaultInstance` won't do that. [...] Always use
>   `Session.getInstance` to avoid this problem.

It is well explained in [JavaMail API FAQ](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#getdefaultinstance). You can also see the consequences of using `Session.getDefaultInstance()` exemplified in this Q&A [hotmail login error in java (IDE: Netbeans)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18389409/1795530)

---

#### Off-topic

The use of multiple JFrame's is also discouraged. See this topic: [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9554636/the-use-of-multiple-jframes-good-bad-practice)